# FFmpeg only works in “terminal,” but is not working via “screen.”

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I’m having a weird problem with FFmpeg.

I’m trying to stream video on a Raspberry Pi to a NodeJS server. When connecting via SSH directly, this command works great:

```
ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video -vf "vflip,hflip" -b:v 800k -r 30 http://localhost:8082/camera/320/240/
```

However, when I try to run the command inside a `screen`, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x21642a0] The device does not support the streaming I/O method.
/dev/video0: Function not implemented
```

I ran the command with the same user. I get the same error when running the command with `sudo`. It also doesn't work in a `systemd` service.

It looks like it doesn't like to run when not in an interactive shell? But I don't know why... Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the `$TERM` value. You could running in screen `export TERM=xterm` or whatever an `env` command shows when you run it in a regular ssh session.

Comment: @bgStack15 you're right! There is `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so` in my environment variables. Apparently this is set in `/etc/environment`. Exporting this variable in my screen session works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment into an answer:

#### Environment variable

ffmpeg depends on the shell environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`.

To make ffmpeg work correctly even when run inside screen, use

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so
```

Comment: The missing environment variable in `screen` was `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so`